# How to select specific fields using getFeatures() without getting all of them in QGIS-3.10

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer, qgsfeaturerequest

So I'm trying to convert code from ArcGIS to QGIS. The part I am at right now is converting:

```
lst_fields = ["full_id", "osm_id", "osm_type", "boundary", "is_in", "leisure", "name", "type", "landuse"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(urh, lst_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
         ...
```

However, with QGIS I have to instead use:

```
with edit(vector_layer):
    for row in vector_layer.getFeatures(request):
```

I did not find a way to get only the fields specified in the list apart from doing another for loop and doing this and then storing the values in another list:

```
row.attributes()[row.fields().indexFromName('boundary')]
```

The code I have right now is:

```
lst_fields = ["full_id", "osm_id", "osm_type", "boundary", "is_in", "leisure", "name", "type", "landuse"]
vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(repertoire+'\\protected_areas.shp','ogr')
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(lst_fields, vector_layer.fields())

with edit(vector_layer):
    for row in vector_layer.getFeatures(request):
        print(lst_fields)
        print(row.fields().names())
```

The first print gives this:

```
['full_id', 'osm_id', 'osm_type', 'boundary', 'is_in', 'leisure', 'name', 'type', 'landuse']
```

The second print gives this:

```
['full_id', 'osm_id', 'osm_type', 'boundary', 'is_in', 'leisure', 'name', 'type', 'wikidata', 'wikipedia', 'landuse', 'name_de', 'sagns_id', 'website']
```

I thought the request would make it so the two prints would give the same result.
I will say what my question is again just in case it wasn't clear:

Is there a way to only get the fields specified in the list like it was possible in arcGIS without the need of another for loop that would save the value of 1 field at a time.

Comment: Right, it's a bit counter intuitive. But, it works in this way: you specify a list of attributes you want to get values from, and then `getFeatures(request)` goes to the data provider and asks for those specific fields, optimizing the query performance. In the response, `fields()` will still give you all field names, but if you print `feature.attributes()` you'll only get values for those from your list (the rest will be None). Now, using your initial list you could ask feature values like this: `for fieldname in my_list: print(feature[fieldname])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German pointed out already that `QgsFeatureRequest.setSubsetOfAttributes([li_required_idx])` returns `None` for any attribute not in `li_required_idx`.
With some list comprehension it is possible to get `li_attr` equal to `li_fields` in the following code:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
li_required_fields = ["POP_EST", "NAME_RU", "POP_DENSITY"]
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(li_required_fields, lyr.fields())

for f in lyr.getFeatures(request):
    li_attr = [attr for attr in f.attributes() if attr is not None]
    print(li_attr)
```

Now all request attributes (`li_required_fields`) are in (`li_attr`). If you want to get 1 attribute at a time, then using the `f[required_attr]` is probably the best approach as German suggested.